# Is there a way to vectorize a conditional sum with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, sum, conditional-statements, vectorization

array I have:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 5, 12, 1, 0, 6])
```

array I need:

```
b = np.array([0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 5, 17, 18, 0, 6])
```

for loop that gives me array b

```
b = np.zeros(a.size)
b[0] = a[0]

for i in range(1, a.size):
    if a[i] > 0:
        b[i] = a[i] + b[i-1]
    else:
        b[i] = 0
```

is there a way to vectorize this type of operation doing that without for loops?

Comment: your examples `a` and `b` don't work syntax-wise

Comment: also: in your example `a[i] < 0` is never `True`, right?

Comment: sorry i'll correct the code

Comment: @ThomasHilger I've adjusted the code sorry for that

Comment: The provided implementation contains a bug, if the first element is >0. Should be `b[0] = a[0]`. `numba.jit` is a trivial option since the code is compile-ready (~300x speedup for larger arrays). Or use `@numba.vectorize` with `def gt_zero(a, b): return a + b if b > 0 else 0` for a custom `ufunc`, usage `gt_zero.accumulate(a)` (~175x speedup). Needs `numba ~0.55.1` because of a bug introduced in `numba 0.51.1`. Even if possible, inherently recursive functions are difficult to vectorize with `numpy` with reasonable effort.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly vectorized, but maybe useful nevertheless

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 5, 12, 1, 0, 6])

b = np.r_[*[np.cumsum(c) for c in np.split(a, np.where(a==0)[0])]]

print(b)
```